# Can't make div block move on arrow button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a div block move on arrow buttons. But it doesn't work. I put the buttons in a table.

```js
document.getElementById("upbutton").onclick = function up() {
  var block = document.getElementById("block");
  var dos = "30px";
  var h = "630px";
  block.style.position = "relative";
  while (block.style.top > h) {
    block.style.top = "300px" + dos + "px";
    dos += "30px";
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="space">
  <div id="block"></div>
  <div id="arrows">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class="arrow"></th>
        <th class="arrow"><button id="upbutton"><img src="up.png"></button></th>
        <th class="arrow"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="arrow"><button id="leftbutton"><img src="left.png"></button></td>
        <td class="arrow"><button id="resetbutton"><img src="reset.jpg"></button></td>
        <td class="arrow"><button id="rightbutton"><img src="right.png"></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="arrow"></td>
        <td class="arrow"><button id="downbutton"><img src="down.png"></button></td>
        <td class="arrow"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are comparing strings not numbers!  "630px" is not 630 (as in number), and in the while loop you are (again) concatenating strings and not adding numbers, and (again!) you are concatenating "30px" to dos `dos += '30px` and not adding the number 30 to it...

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of things wrong with your code

- You cannot add string to an integer it will result to string
  concatenation.     If you add `"300px"+ 10` it will result to
  `300px10` not `310px`
- I can't understand your logic what you are trying to do but 
  `while (block.style.top > h) {` will never pass as style of block will be in string again `0px` at start and `h` is `630`.
  you have use `parseInt(block.style.top)` in while loop  to compare.
- Your div block has no width and height or color you can't see anything.

**Here is my implementation of moving a div using arrows.**

Store your position to a object pos `var pos = {top:0,left:0};`

then add events to your buttons

**UP:**

Update the `pos.top+=dos` value and apply it to the `block.style.top = pos.top+'px';`

```
document.getElementById("upbutton").onclick = function up() {
  //Update if top is not equal to zero not allowed to go out of window.
  if(pos.top!=0) {pos.top-=dos; block.style.top = pos.top+'px';}
};
```

**Down:**

Update the `pos.top-=dos` value and apply it to the `block.style.top = pos.top+'px';`

```
document.getElementById("downbutton").onclick = function down() {
  if(pos.top<h) {pos.top+=dos; block.style.top = pos.top+'px';}
};
```

**Left:**

Update the `pos.left-=dos` value and apply it to the `block.style.left = pos.left+'px';`

```
document.getElementById("leftbutton").onclick = function left() {
  if(pos.left!=0) {pos.left-=dos; block.style.left = pos.left+'px';}
};
```

**Right:**

Update the `pos.left+=dos` value and apply it to the `block.style.left = pos.left+'px';`

```
document.getElementById("rightbutton").onclick = function right() {
  if(pos.top<h) {pos.left+=dos; block.style.left = pos.left+'px';}
};
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
var dos = 30;
var h = 630;
var block = document.getElementById("block");
var pos = {top:0,left:0};
 
document.getElementById("upbutton").onclick = function up() {
  if(pos.top!=0) {pos.top-=dos; block.style.top = pos.top+'px';}
};

document.getElementById("downbutton").onclick = function up() {
  if(pos.top<h) {pos.top+=dos; block.style.top = pos.top+'px';}
};

document.getElementById("leftbutton").onclick = function up() {
  if(pos.left!=0) {pos.left-=dos; block.style.left = pos.left+'px';}
};

document.getElementById("rightbutton").onclick = function up() {
  if(pos.top<h) {pos.left+=dos; block.style.left = pos.left+'px';}
};
```

```css
#block{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  background-color:red;
}

#arrows{
   position:relative;
   z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<div id="space">
  <div id="block" style="top:0px"></div>
  <div id="arrows">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class="arrow"></th>
        <th class="arrow"><button id="upbutton"><img src="up.png"></button></th>
        <th class="arrow"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="arrow"><button id="leftbutton"><img src="left.png"></button></td>
        <td class="arrow"><button id="resetbutton"><img src="reset.jpg"></button></td>
        <td class="arrow"><button id="rightbutton"><img src="right.png"></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="arrow"></td>
        <td class="arrow"><button id="downbutton"><img src="down.png"></button></td>
        <td class="arrow"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also doesn't work.The string method are logic,because the loop will compare the ord. number of characters from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd go about this:

```js
var block = document.getElementById("block");

function adjustPos(dX, dY) {
  block.style.left = parseInt(block.style.left) + dX + 'px';
  block.style.top = parseInt(block.style.top) + dY + 'px';
}

document.getElementById("upbutton").onclick = () => adjustPos(0, -10);
document.getElementById("leftbutton").onclick = () => adjustPos(-10, 0);
document.getElementById("rightbutton").onclick = () => adjustPos(10, 0);
document.getElementById("downbutton").onclick = () => adjustPos(0, 10);
```

```css
#block {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="space">
  <div id="block" style="top: 100px; left: 100px;"></div>
  <div id="arrows">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class="arrow"></th>
        <th class="arrow">
          <button id="upbutton">⇑</button>
        </th>
        <th class="arrow"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="arrow">
          <button id="leftbutton">⇐</button>
        </td>
        <td class="arrow">
          <button id="resetbutton">ⓧ</button>
        </td>
        <td class="arrow">
          <button id="rightbutton">⇒</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="arrow"></td>
        <td class="arrow">
          <button id="downbutton">⇓</button>
        </td>
        <td class="arrow"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The key insight is that you need to parse the string as an int (this removes the trailing 'px'.  Then you can add it back.

Also, your block needs to use `position: fixed` to be positioned wherever on the page.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an start point.

```js
var block = document.getElementById("block");
document.getElementById("upbutton").onclick = function up() {
adjustPos(0, -10);
};

document.getElementById("leftbutton").onclick = function up() {
adjustPos(-10, 0);
};

document.getElementById("rightbutton").onclick = function up() {
adjustPos(10, 0);
};

document.getElementById("downbutton").onclick = function up() {
adjustPos(0, 10);
};

document.getElementById("resetbutton").onclick = function up() {
  block.style.left = 50 + 'px';
  block.style.top = 50 + 'px';
};

function adjustPos(dX, dY) {
  block.style.left = parseInt(block.style.left) + dX + 'px';
  block.style.top = parseInt(block.style.top) + dY + 'px';
}
```

```html
<div id="space" style="width:100px;height:100px">
<div  id="block" style="background-color: black;position: relative;width: 10px;height: 10px; top:50px; left:50px"></div>
</div>

<div id="arrows">
<table>
<tr>
<th class="arrow"></th>
<th class="arrow"><button id="upbutton"><img src="up.png"></img></button></th>
<th class="arrow"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="arrow"><button id="leftbutton"><img src="left.png"></img></button></td>
<td class="arrow"><button id="resetbutton"><img src="reset.jpg"></img></button></td>
<td class="arrow"><button id="rightbutton"><img src="right.png"></img></button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="arrow"></td>
<td class="arrow"><button id="downbutton"><img src="down.png"></img></button></td>
<td class="arrow"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried this JS code but still doesn't work with adds or no.